# How to make a makefile with two executables in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am still learning and I have two similar programs which outputs the same result. I uam using vectors in one program and dynamic arrays in another. I want to make a makefile which can produce separate executables for each version of the program.I know I will encounter this scenario later in my programming too and want to learn how to do it now. Here is what i have done until now:

```
CC = g++

CFLAGS  = -g -Wall -std=c++11

TARGET1 = testCountry1
TARGET2 = testCountry2
MAIN1 = country1
MAIN2 = country2

all: $(TARGET1) $(TARGET2)

$(TARGET1): $(MAIN1).o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET1) $(MAIN1).o

$(MAIN1).o: $(MAIN1).cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(MAIN1).cpp

$(TARGET2): $(MAIN2).o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET2) $(MAIN2).o

$(MAIN2).o: $(MAIN2).cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(MAIN2).cpp
clean:
    $(RM) -f $(TARGET1) $(MAIN1).o $(TARGET2) $(MAIN2).o
```

Is there a better way to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: whats your problem, that makefile looks OK

Comment: I was thinking is there a better way to do it?

Comment: While it could be simplified (use [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html) to build the object files, etc.) there doesn't seem to be anything directly wrong with the makefile as you show it. What problems does it give you? What happens when you try to use it to build your programs?

Comment: is it that country1.cpp and country1.c basically the same file - is that your issue , and you want to compile them in different ways. Or is it that you think this is a bit long winded (since the instructions to build main1 and main1 are basically the same

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Please specify your problem and what you need help with, in as much details as you can.

Comment: There is noproblem with the build. I was just repeating the things and was wondering if it could have been done in a simpler way. Everything is working out fine actually.

Comment: @pm100 country1.cpp and country2.cpp are two different files with different code. Yes , it was looking a bit longer as I am repeating things.

Comment: Read [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html#Top). Learn about [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html) (already mentioned). Learn about [the automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables). Remember to add possible header files to the dependency lists of the object files.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I will read the suggested links.